# How to implement onItemClickListener with a custom array adapter?

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I have been searching about this issue but still I am not very clear on how to use a click listener with an array adapter.

I need a click listener for each item of the list.

Codes:

The Area item:

```
package fogames.tamagomonsters;

public class Area {

    public String name;
    public String number;

    public Area(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

The array adapter:

```
package fogames.tamagomonsters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class AreasAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Area> {
    public AreasAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Area> Areas) {
        super(context, 0, Areas);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Area Area = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_area, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView tvname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName_area);
        TextView tvnumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNumber_of_beasts);
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        tvname.setText(Area.name);
        tvnumber.setText(Area.number);
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The activity:

```
package fogames.tamagomonsters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PlayMenuActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
        fl.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));

        // Construct the data source
        ArrayList<Area> arrayOfAreas = new ArrayList<Area>();
// Create the adapter to convert the array to views
        AreasAdapter adapter = new AreasAdapter(this, arrayOfAreas);

// Attach the adapter to a ListView
        ListView lv = new ListView(this);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Restore preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PreferenceConstants.PREFERENCE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        int mlen = prefs.getInt(PreferenceConstants.MLEN, 0);
        long money = prefs.getLong(PreferenceConstants.MONEY, 0);
        int mall = 6; //hay que ver que hacer con esto...
        int eqall = 3; //igual
        boolean[] mgot = new boolean[mall];
        int[] exp = new int[eqall];
        int[] lvl = new int[eqall];
        int[] at = new int[eqall];
        int[] en = new int[eqall];
        for (int i = 0; i < mall; i++) {
            mgot[i] = prefs.getBoolean(PreferenceConstants.MGOT[i], false);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < eqall; i++) {
            exp[i] = prefs.getInt(PreferenceConstants.EXP[i], 0);
            lvl[i] = prefs.getInt(PreferenceConstants.LVL[i], 0);
            at[i] = prefs.getInt(PreferenceConstants.AT[i], 0);
            en[i] = prefs.getInt(PreferenceConstants.EN[i], 0);
        }

        String name[] = {getString(R.string.a001)};

        int prado_got = 0;
        if (mgot[0]) {
            prado_got += 1;
        }

        if (mgot[3]) {
            prado_got += 1;
        }

        String prado = String.valueOf(prado_got) + " / 2";

        String number[] = {prado};

        // Add item to adapter
        Area a001 = new Area(name[0], number[0]);
        adapter.add(a001);


        this.setContentView(fl);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that:

•First insert in your adapter this method

```
@Override
public Area getItem(int position) {
        return [yourArrayAreas].get(position);
}
```

•Then, in your Activity...

```
final AreasAdapter adapter = new AreasAdapter(this, arrayOfAreas);

ListView lv = new ListView(this);

lv.setAdapter(adapter);

mListStopsMuni.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id{

Area yourClickArea = adapter.getItem(position);

//Rest of code...

}
});
```

Good luck ;)

Comment: In this case, what sould I write instead of  [yourArrayAreas]?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
ArrayList<Area> arrayListAreas;
public AreasAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Area> Areas) {
        super(context, 0, Areas);
        this.arrayListAreas = Areas;
}

//And then....
@Override
public Area getItem(int position) {
        return arrayListAreas.get(position);
}
```